# How to send nvim selection to terminal in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, neovim

I want to make an nvim-selection in VSCode and sent this to the terminal using Shift-Enter.
I am aware that nvim selections in VSCode are no VSCode selections as per the first point
under *Important* [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=asvetliakov.vscode-neovim).

However I am a complete noob in Vimscript and would appreciate an exact instruction to how to make that
work (I am sourcing my .vimrc from VSCode)